# Why is python's set datastructure an invalid type with MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, set, pymongo

I am trying to store data in a dictionary and python's 'set' is also stored in the dictionary.

When I try to store this dictionary in MongoDB, an "InvalidDocument" exception is thrown. On searching around, I found that "set" is not supported by MongoDB.

Why is set not supported by MongoDB? What is the reason behind it? Is there a work-around for it?

Comment: *Why is set not supported* quickly deteriorates into opinions. It doesn't, so you'll have to deal with the work-arounds available. See the duplicates.

Comment: (I'd say that `dict.fromkeys(yourset, "")` looks like a viable alternative, if Mongo is okay with empty strings for the values).